# angularjs service is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, angularjs-service

I have a service like so:

```
app.service('Utilities', function() {
  this.sum = function(items, prop) {
    var count, total;
    total = 0;
    count = 0;
    if (items === null) {
      total = 0;
    }
    while (count < items.length) {
      total += items[count][prop] * 1 || 0;
      count++;
    }
    return total;
  };
});
```

and a controller like so:

```
app.controller('writeCtrl', function($scope, Utilities, students) {
  $scope.students = students;
  $scope.total_age = Utilities.sum($scope.students, 'age');
});
```

And I keep getting the error

> Typerror: Utilities.sum is not a function

Which is confusing because about a dozen other functions under the Utilities service is working fine. What's causing the issue, and how do I get the function to work?

**Edit**
Actual Coffeescript version

```
app.service 'Utilities', ->
  @sum = (items, prop) ->
    total = 0
    count = 0
    if items == null
      total = 0
    while count < items.length
      total += (items[count][prop]*1 || 0)
      count++
    return total

app.controller 'writeCtrl', ($scope, Utilities, students) ->
  $scope.students = students
  $scope.total_age = Utilities.sum($scope.students, 'age')
```

**Solution:**

Coffeescript functions need a return:

```
App.service 'Utilities', -> 
  .....
  return
```

Comment: Is this the correct indentation of your code? CoffeeScript is whitespace significant and it would appear you have an indentation error on line 3

Comment: @DanPantry Hi Dan, the indentation must've got messed up when I pasted it on stackoverflow, but yes the indentation in my actual code is correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Service never returns an object, basically it binds a method or variable to its context; nothing but `this` & then it returns a new `object` which contains all the things which were binded to `this`.

**Code**

```
app.service('Utilities', function() {
  this.sum = function(items, prop) {
    var count, total;
    total = 0;
    count = 0;
    if (items === null) {
      total = 0;
    }
    while (count < items.length) {
      total += items[count][prop] * 1 || 0;
      count++;
    }
    return total;
  };

  //
  // ..other utility method should lies here..
  //..do your stuff
});
```

**Update**

You should change your coffee script service from

```
app.service 'Utilities' ->
```

to

```
app.service 'Utilities' () ->
```

Comment: sorry, it's a typo from the js2coffee app. I'm using @sum = (items, prop) -> with coffeescript.

Comment: @Ryan.lay paste your actual code instead of a transpiled version.

Comment: @Ryan.lay could you update you code then..what you have in your code

Comment: @Ryan.lay it doesn't seems like you have updated your question..Could you please do update it with proper code..

Comment: @PankajParkar give him time. He might be busy. You've only given him 10 minutes to update his code. Most of my meetings in work last more than 10 minutes.

Comment: @DanPantry np dude.. he could take his own time.. :)

Comment: @PankajParkar Thanks for your patience, I've updated my code.

Comment: @Ryan.lay I think you should try change `app.service 'Utilities' ()->` instead of `app.service 'Utilities' ->`

Comment: @Ryan.lay as you said in your question `dozen other functions under the Utilities service is working fine` where are you are written this other functions..

Comment: Changing the `() ->` is a superficial change and will not fix the issue. `->` and `()->` evaluate the same.

Comment: ARRGHHH rookie mistake. I was missing the return at the end of the Utilities service. The return was accidentally overwritten when I added the sum function. Thank you so much for your time and effort Pankaj and @DanPantry.

Comment: Glad to help you..Thanks..@DanPantry why you don't feel question should shouldn't havr angularjs-service tag?

Comment: @PankajParkar I've posted my [thoughts about that on the meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296857/burninate-73-angularjs-directive-tags#comment222234_296857), when I first looked at the tag I didn't see it had so many questions attached to it and it gave me the impression you were creating a new tag. So I apologize for removing it, that was inappropriate of me.